# How to create Drop down menu in a button click

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I need a balloon image showing a list of items in a button click.(as a drop down menu).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean QuickAction Menu. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).